# How to use layout_gravity="start" either layout_gravity="LEFT" in Navigation view Programatically in Android

Tags: android, drawerlayout, android-navigationview

> My problem is that when the language  is Arabic then i want to DrawerLayout open with the gravity of RIGHT and when the language will English then to DrawerLayout open with the gravity of Left.......

Comment: If you have `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the manifest, it will do that automatically with `android:layout_gravity="start"`. If yours is not, you'll need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `end` and `start` keywords instead of `left` and `right`, to achieve this

like `android:layout_gravity="end"`

Also, add this to your manifest > application `android:supportsRtl="true"`

Comment: i also use android:supportsRtl="true" in manifest but not work......
As you say 
You can use end and start keywords instead of left and right, to achieve this
like android:layout_gravity="end"

but i want to use it programatically

Comment: Hmm, Can you pls check this, I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android